# Changing Axis Range with Datepicker

Tags: java, python, datepicker, bokeh

I have a plot with datetime values in the x axis and want to change the range with a datepicker widget. But there is a problem with the "cb_obj.value", which cannot be directly used for f.x_range.start . 
 I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303605/python-bokeh-how-to-change-range-of-datetime-axis), which was solved. However, I still have a lot of trouble to adjust/convert my value from the callback object, especially because this has to be done in Java. Or, am I wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, DatePicker, TextInput, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import row, layout
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show, figure
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

output_file("DatePicker.html")

# Figure
f=figure(x_axis_type='datetime')

# Datetime
date_time = [datetime(2017,1,1) + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,365)]

# ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(datetime=date_time, parameter=np.random.rand(365)))

# Line for plot
f.line(x='datetime',y='parameter',line_color='black',source=source)

# Callback
callbackPlot= CustomJS(args=dict(f=f), code="""
    var a = cb_obj.value;
    f.x_range.start = a;
""")

# Datepicker
DatepickerPlot = DatePicker(
    title="Start:", name="StartDate",  value=date_time[0])
DatepickerPlot.js_on_change('value', callbackPlot)

# Show 
show(layout(row(DatepickerPlot, f)))
```

Apart from that, is there another option to make a standalone HTML file in Bokeh with callbacks without using CustomJS/Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cb_obj.value` is a string, and `f.x_range.start` need a number, change

```
f.x_range.start = a;
```

to

```
f.x_range.start = Date.parse(a);
```